# wso2 : Can't log in API publisher and store via tenant admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Environment : wso2 API-M + wso2 Identity server (Key manager) and they shared the same user store.

1.I set SSO with publisher and store. (done)

2.I integrate Social account to the environment. (done)

3.I create 2 tenants which called TA, TB. (done)

4.TA admin try to log in to publisher and store. (Fail)

Error logs:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-14 15:08:24,615] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Service Provider tenant domain must be equal to user tenant domain for non-SaaS applications 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: Service Provider tenant domain must be equal to user tenant domain for non-SaaS applications 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:73) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator.process(BasicAuthenticator.java:78) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:432) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:406) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:117)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:171) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:115) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:135) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:974) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:159) 
        at
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:107) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) 
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) 
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) 
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
        at.....

org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) 
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) 
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Questions:

1.About : **Service Provider tenant domain must be equal to user tenant domain for non-SaaS applications**

How should I change Service Provider tenant domain in the Service provider?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't change the service provider's tenant domain. It will be same as the tenant domain of the user who created it.

So say you created a service provider in tenant TA and want to allow tenant admin (or any other user) from TB to use the service provider to do SSO, then you should enable SaaS application option in the service provider. This allows the Service Provider to be used by users who are not from the same tenant domain as the service provider.

[image]

As shown above, simply tick the SaaS application in the Service Provider configuration. Then  users from TB also can SSO using the Service Provider in TA

Comment: Does wso2 API-M can set multi issuer for SSO service if I create new service providers for publisher/store in TB? I wanna let all tenants has their own publisher and use common store under the SSO architecture.

Comment: In that case, create a service provider from API store and make it a SaaS application.

Comment: I've set a SaaS store for all tenant, but all tenants are directed to carbon tenant while logging in publisher. How should I direct tenants to their own publisher?

Comment: how are you redirecting the tenants to the publisher?
can you try sending 
tenantDomain=<tenantDomainName> as a query param in the redirect url

Comment: Coz I enable SSO for API-M, in <AM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.json, it assign to the specific issuer ID so that it will be redirected to the tenant of the publisher service provider. In fact, other tenant user can't log in the publisher if I disable SaaS of the publisher service provider.

Comment: I also try to sending tenantDomain=<tenantDomainName>, but it will be redirected to original domain while deploying API.

Comment: can you add a new SO question for the publisher issue and put the link here?

Comment: Here you are. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851451/wso2-cant-login-to-correct-publisher-tenant

Comment: Keep the same configurations, I try to use Restful API to do the story and it works. So I think it may be a bug in API-M UI.

Comment: how did you get the scenario working? did you send the tenantDomain in the url as a query param?

Comment: What I just try is : 1.Use https://my-ip/client-registration/v0.9/register to login to publsher. 2.Use other API to deploy API. 3.Publish API and go to store UI to check it.

Comment: After that, I try to disable publisher SP SaaS.......it still works. Now I wanna use API to verify if SSO works but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Are there any saml restful api in Idp for SSO?

Comment: as of now there is no restful API for saml sso. By the way my-ip/client-registration/v0.9/register

Comment: I try to use wso2 demo project for SSO, does the demo project login page also use saml? I try to login via demo login page to get the credential and then use it to operate APIs of API-M, it works.I'm not sure if SSO is effective in this situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114904/discussion-between-farasath-and-).

Comment: When do you have free time to discuss?