# wso2: Can't login to correct publisher tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Environment :

- wso2 API-M + wso2 Identity server (Key manager) and they shared the
  same user store.
- 2 service providers(publisher and store) and 2 identity providers(Google and Facebook) in the carbon.super tenant.
- SSO service enabled and issuer IDs follow above.
- Enable OAuth2.0 users(Google and Facebook) to login.
- 3 tenants (carbon.super , TA and TB) in the environment.

What I tried:

- Social accounts can login to publisher and store and they will be directed to carbon.super publisher.
- TA users can't login to publisher without publisher SP SaaS enabled.(Service Provider tenant domain must be equal to user tenant domain for non-SaaS applications)
- TA and TB users can login to publisher with publisher SP SaaS
  enabled but they will be redirected to carbon.super tenant.
- TA/TB user can browse their own tenant publisher while they try to
  sending tenantDomain=, but it will be redirected to carbon.super publisher and deploy API on carbon.super publisher when users  deploy APIs to publisher.(The API will be published on carbon.super store.)

What I want :

- Tenant users can login to correct tenant publisher and deploy API on
  it with SSO.(Social account login to carbon.super tenant is fine.)

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I try to use API-M restful API to do it but I think it skips the SSO setting. Maybe IdP restful API can solve it if IdP have SSO login API to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have another security mechanism they need to write CXF handler and plug it to web applications. It’s always recommended to use one or more security mechanisms with this API as users can do almost all critical operations using these APIs.

You can change the CXF interceptor by editing WEB-INF/beans.xml files. You can see the following entry for the security interceptor.

By default API Manager REST API use OAuth 2.0 and do not use SSO based authentication for the REST API. However if you need to do assertion based validation let API access then you can do that with CXF interceptor as mentioned above.

Thanks,

sanjeewa.

Comment: So...while I create multiple tenants in API-M, all the tenants have their own  store but only one common publisher?

Comment: In the publisher you will not be able to view APIs without login to system. It was designed that way because someone do not need to just see what APIs are there from publisher. They go for publisher to edit or modify APIs. So when you login to publisher based on the logged in user you will automatically direct to relevant tenants publisher. For example if you logged as test@abc.com then you will go to abc.com tenant publisher. And you will see only abc.com tenant created APIs.

Comment: I agree you said above. But the problem I met is : tenant admin and users only can login in carbon.super publisher, and now, tenant admin and users can't login to any publishers or stores. I connected to Traveena yesterday for asking support, maybe you can see the whole issue on WSO2 support system for us, thank you~